# Get node path relative to the SConstruct from inside a SConscript

Tags: scons

In a hierarchical build, one of my `SConscript` files, located in a sub-directory needs to print paths of a few nodes (for use by an external script). However, the paths need to be relative to the main directory, in which `SConstruct` resides, not to the sub-directory I'm currently in.

The functions I'm normally use to get node paths are `str(node)` and `node.get_path()`. Both of them return the path relative to the sub-directory.

How can I get a path relative to the root directory of the project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node object have two properties that appear to store paths relative to the root directory:

- `node.path`
- `node.relpath`

([link to the manual](https://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-man.html#node_objects))

Their descriptions are kinda similar, although, from what information I've managed to gather, `node.path` is preferable.